# Static cast return type

Tags: c++, explicit

While compiling i get a non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'int' to result_type. This error occurs at the highlighted place. How would i chance it to a static_cast(). I am having trouble figure out what i need to change.

```
   class UniformRandom
    {
      public:
        **UniformRandom( int seed = currentTimeSeconds( ) ) : generator{ seed }**
        {
        }

      private:
        mt19937 generator;

    };
```

Comment: Can't tell what's going on by looking at the posted code. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: `generator` has a type narrower than `int` (or a floating point type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are using `{}` to initialize `generator`.And form the standard draft n4296: `If a narrowing conversion is required to initialize any of the elements, the program is ill-formed.` when using `{}`.

Form the standard draft n4296:

> A narrowing conversion is an implicit conversion
>
> — from a floating-point type to an integer type, or
>
> — from long double to double or float, or from double to float, except where the source is a constant expression and the actual value after conversion is within the range of values that can be represented (even if it cannot be represented exactly), or
>
> — from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to a floating-point type, except where the source is a constant expression and the actual value after conversion will fit into the target type and will produce the original value when converted back to the original type, or
>
> — from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to an integer type that cannot represent all the values of the original type, except where the source is a constant expression whose value after integral promotions will fit into the target type.

---

An example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a = {1.2};
    return 0;
}
```

It gives the error: `error: narrowing conversion of '1.2e+0' from 'double' to 'int' inside { } [-Wnarrowing] int a = {1.2};`

---

### To solve this problem:

`generator{seed}` => `generator(seed)`.

Comment: This explains the error the OP is getting, but the OP isn't asking for an explanation of the error, the OP is asking how to fix the code. You're not answering that.

Comment: So he just need change `generator{ seed }` into `generator(seed)`.I hope he can know more about why this error happened.And I think it will be easy for him to solve this problem when he knows the reason.